# A page is not loaded

Tags: python, html, django

A page is not loaded.
I got no error, but surely link is not good.
I wrote in html file like,

```
<button type="button" name="results" url="{% url 'results' %}">
<font size="10">Resulyshow</font>
 </button>
```

in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^results$',  TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/accounts/result.html'), name='results'),
]
```

I think,I should write `url(..., name='page_name')` in urls.py and `{% url 'page_name' %}` in html file.So,I wrote these code, but they could not work well.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't put url inside a button. And

```
<font size="10">
```

isn't correct html either. You should include font-size in your css. Like this:

```
button {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

This will make all buttons use 10 px font size.

If there's no form on the page and you just want to redirect the user after clicking on the button, you should use a link instead of the button. Like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'results' %}">
```

You can add a class to it if you want to use css styling.

If there's a form in your html, and your button is inside that form, you should specify an **action** attribute in that form with the url where this form will be submitted to and the method. Like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'results' %}" method="POST">
```

If that form includes file inputs, you should add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

into it.

If you want the form to be sumbittem into this page url, it's done like this:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
```

Hope it helps.